# Grails export plugin && show jquery spinner

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a grails application with a http-link to a controller export method.
This creates an excel-file and send it to the browser. This can take several minutes.

I now creates a `spinner.gif` and show this when the user clicks on the export link via `$('#wait').show();`. This spinner blocks the whole application! (that was the plan :-) )

The problem now is, how can I hide the spinner again. I found no method in JQuery with can be handle the event `"Excel-File was sent to browser"`.

Even when I try to redirect the page after the export call in the controller, I get an error, because there might be only one answer (document) sent to the requesting browser.

Is there an easy way, if any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download